# Tracking a ReactJS application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reactjs, google-analytics, virtual-dom

I have been working with **AngularJS** and its structure is in a way that, as the user browses around the website, only views and routes change and there are no **pageviews** and etc triggered (GTM is not loaded per route).

Hence, I have faced quite a number of issues in Google analytics (*even [Angulartics](http://angulartics.github.io/) is not too promising*), when working with AngularJS websites.

Now I am reading on **ReactJS**, and I am very keen to use it along with **Laravel**. I am only concerned that the entire ***virtual DOM concept*** of React, would indeed create a similar tracking pain afterwards, as it would mean that the Google Tag Manager container might not be loaded every time a user lands on a page.

Anybody facing issues tracking React applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mount React to a given DOM element, which then becomes a mount root element. Only these elements will be changed, meaning that if you have script tags and alike, not inside react, these will not be affected

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="/gtm.js"></script>
    <script src="/react.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="mount">
    </div>
    <script>
      class Test extends React.Component {
        track() {
          window.dataLayer.push({
            event: 'Stuff'
          });
        }

        render() {
          return <button onClick={this.track} />;
        }
      }
      React.render(<Test />, document.getElementById('mount'))
    </script>
</html>
```

In that React can only modify in content inside `#mount`, and therefore the gtm tag should always be present.

Comment: Right, so gtm.js in this case, will NOT be **loaded again** whenever I switch pages (routes). Is that right?